# Data Factory job failing to submit to Azure Batch?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I'm trying to submit a Data Factory pipeline to Azure Batch compute, with a linked service that I have previously been using and works fine.

However, the pipeline is failing with the following message:

Azure Batch entity not found. Code: 'JobNotFound' Message: 'The specified job does not exist. RequestId:d8f2b8d6-b34b-4823-9a06-9037ff549185 Time:2016-05-26T10:21:43.1480686Z'

The two sentences seem inconsistent, one states that the batch entity wasn't found, thought code says JobNotFound, which is referring to a Azure Batch Job.

Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by deleting the batch account, and creating a new one with a different name.
Could not figure out what was causing the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems that ADF is having a hard time. Moreover ADF seems unstable and slow.